# Invalid cast exception while trying to set control visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this control in a `ItemTemplate` inside a `GridView`:

```
<img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" runat="server" 
     id="img_expand1" />
```

I need to set the visibility to false in a condition:

```
 else
 {
    Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img_expand1");
    img.Visible = false;
 }
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Invalid cast exception. Impossible to cast object type
'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage' on type
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage img = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage)e.Row.FindControl("img_expand1");
img.Visible = false;
```